# Passing a variable from PHP to ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, variables

I want to run a script on my ubuntu server with a variable from php in it.

Here are some of the things i've tried to pass a variable to ubuntu...

```
shell_exec('vpsName=HI3');

vpsName=`mysql -D jake_db -h 127.0.0.1 -u jake -pXXXXXXX -se "SELECT vpsName FROM reinstalls WHERE status = 'pending'"`;
```

The final way in which i thought I could fix it was to avoid running the script through ubuntu all together and run it from shell_exec(); but it fails on running the guestfish commands.

Here is my entire reinstalls.sh script.

```
    sudo rm /var/lib/libvirt/images/"$vpsName".qcow2 && sudo wget -O /var/lib/libvi$
guestfish -a /var/lib/libvirt/images/"$vpsName".qcow2 <<'EOF'
 run
 mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /
  rm /etc/network/interfaces
EOF
sudo fusermount -u /mnt && virsh start "$vpsName" && echo "IT WORKED!"
```

I am open to any way of getting this to work, as long as its secure,
Thanks in advance, 
Jake

EDIT:
If I run the script with a VPS name instead of a variable, it works. I just can't find a way to pass the variables from the website to the ubuntu16.04 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way would be to run each command from PHP:

```
shell_exec("sudo rm /var/lib/libvirt/images/" . $vpsName . ".qcow2");
shell_exec("sudo wget -O /var/lib/libvi ... etc");
```

The other would be to invoke your shell script from PHP, passing the vps name as a parameter:

```
shell_exec("reinstalls.sh " . $vpsName)
```

But then you'd have to rewrite the shell script to pick up the command line parameter and apply it as necessary. In the case of bash, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash#192266) explains how to go about that.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working by passing it as a parameter like you said and doing vpsName=$1. Thanks for the help!